# How to check enyo version?

Tags: javascript, enyo

How can I programmatically check which enyo version am using? I have a JavaScript module that requires enyo, it can run on top of different versions so I want to know which is the current one.

Is there anything like `enyo.getVersion()`?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the file name and first few lines of it? Maybe version is specified there?

Comment: @Pavlo, thanks, but I want to do it from the code itself. I have a javascript module that requires enyo, it can run on top of different versions so I want to know which is the current one.

Comment: I've added this to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, prior to the recent code in GitHub, we didn't include the version number of Enyo.  In the latest pilot releases you have `enyo.version` which is a hash containing version information. The current Enyo version is in `enyo.version.enyo`.  There are also version numbers for the individual modules as well:  e.g. `enyo.version.onyx`